# PCA Algorithm & Residual in R

Tags: r, pca

I'm studying the PCA algorithm. But I have a problem with the residuals. I did the same as in the manual below until step 5. From step 6, I don't quite understand the idea, as the dimensions of $Y$ and $\tilde Y$ are different.

How can I calculate the residual?

[image]

Comment: Could some explain a little bit  about multivariate transformation technique and in this case, how to calculate the residual.